# Error when initializing variable at the time of declaration php

Tags: php, syntax-error

when I try to initialize variable while declaring I get `syntax error: unexpected T_VARIABLE.`  Here is my code:

```
class TagProduct extends CI_Controller {

// num of records per page
private $limit = 10;
private $CurrentDate;
private $LoginID=$this->session->userdata('UserID');
private $Errmsg=array(
                        'TagErr'=>'',
                        'ProductErr'=>'',
                    );

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
```

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): `declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value - that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`

Comment: @kumar_v how is the codeigniter tag relevant?

Comment: @Matsemann Yes. He is extending CI_controller. We can use some CI concept for his case.

Comment: thanks.it worked now by initializing inside constructor.

Comment: @kumar_v ok, I was set to review your edit and needed to know if it was correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties must be initialized by constants in **PHP**:

Use Structure like this:

```
class TagProduct extends CI_Controller {

private $limit;

    function __construct() {
        $this->limit = 10;
    }
}
```

[Check in php.net](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)